# python: Numbering each entry respective to the kind

Tags: python, sorting, file-io, formatting

I have data that look something like this:

```
car    trans  +  1,4,6,8
plane  trans  +  3,5,7,9,4,3
train  trans  -  2,4,6,7
bus    trans  -  1,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

That needs to be organized in the below format. I basically want to take "eventh" number from 4th column and place it on 4th column it it is "+" or on 5th column if it is "-". Then if its "+"  I want to add 1 to its value and place it in the 5th column. If it's "-", I want to subtract 1 and place it on its 4th column

```
car.1    trans  +  4  5
car.2    trans  +  8  9
plane.1  trans  +  5  6
plane.2  trans  +  9  10
plane.3  trans  +  3  4
train.1  trans  -  3  4
train.2  trans  -  6  7
bus.1    trans  -  2  3
bus.2    trans  -  4  5
bus.3    trans  -  6  7
```

The following is the code I have right now. This gives the output I wanted but only problem is that the names on the first column is not ordered as I wanted. (car.1,car.2) I know I have to direct it on the output.write() line but I am not sure how to make a string that will number the elements on comma-separated values in original data. Please help me!

```
import sys
import string
infileName = sys.argv[1]
outfileName = sys.argv[2]

def getGenes(infile, outfile):

    infile = open(infileName,"r")
    outfile = open(outfileName, "w")

    while 1:
       line = infile.readline()
       if not line: break
       wrds = string.split(line)
       comma = string.split(wrds[3], ",")
       fivess = comma[1::2]


    if len(wrds) >= 2:
        name = wrds[0]
        chr = wrds[1]
        type = wrds[2]
        print(type)
    if type == "+":
        for jj in fivess:
            start = jj
            stop = string.atoi(jj)+1
            outfile.write('%s%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' %(name, , chr, type, start, stop))           
    elif type == "-":
        for jj in fivess:
            stop = jj
            start= string.atoi(jj)-1
            outfile.write('%s%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' %(name, ,chr, type, start, stop))   




getGenes(infileName, outfileName)
```

Comment: Have you considered putting the processed data in a `list` and then using `list.sort()` to give the order you want before writing it back out?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was just going to suggest the exact same thing. If the default text-order sort isn't up to snuff (at first glance it appears that it should be), you can use the `key` argument to pass in a function for comparison

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't have to do so on the `output.write()` line.  Ideally, you should do it with your input, so you can just sort properly at first and then process without having to think of the order.  Here is the code I wrote, using yours as a framework but clarifying/error-proofing a few things:

```
import sys

infileName_s = sys.argv[1]
outfileName_s = sys.argv[2]

def getGenes(infileName, outfileName):

    infile = open(infileName,"r")
    outfile = open(outfileName, "w")

    x = infile.read()
    infile.close()   # make sure to close infile and outfile
    data = x.split('\n')
    alldata = []
    for line in data:
        alldata.append(line.split())
        alldata[-1][-1] = alldata[-1][-1].split(',')

    alldata = sorted(alldata) # sort

    mod_alldata = []

    for line in alldata: # create data structures
        for i in range(1, len(line[-1]), 2):
            if line[2] == '+':
                mod_alldata.append([line[0]+'.'+str(i/2+1), line[1], line[2], line[3][i], int(line[3][i])+1])
            else:
                mod_alldata.append([line[0]+'.'+str(i/2+1), line[1], line[2], int(line[3][i])-1, line[3][i]])

    for line in mod_alldata: # write to file
        outfile.write(line[0] + '\t' + line[1]+ '\t' + line[2] + '\t' + str(line[3]) + '\t' + str(line[4]) + '\n')
    outfile.close()

getGenes(infileName_s, outfileName_s)
```

Things to note:

- **ALWAYS** close files that you open.
- Be careful with variable scope--you used `infileName`/`infile` and `outfileName`/`outfile` differently both inside and outside of your function.
- Using a `range` with step size of 2 (as I do here: `range(1, len(line[-1]), 2)`) was super-helpful with iterating through even indices, and it's also robust in the case of odd-numbered/empty lists.
- I sorted alphabetically using `sorted()` because I didn't know how you wanted them sorted.  If you want them sorted differently just let me know in a comment.

This is the output into the specified text file:

```
bus.1   trans   -   2   3
bus.2   trans   -   4   5
bus.3   trans   -   6   7
car.1   trans   +   4   5
car.2   trans   +   8   9
plane.1 trans   +   5   6
plane.2 trans   +   9   10
plane.3 trans   +   3   4
train.1 trans   -   3   4
train.2 trans   -   6   7
```